# sql oracle - return days with max value for each day

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to return the detail for each day, but only the detail associated with the max ID_EXECN for each day. Here is my code:

```
SELECT
T1.ID_EXECN,     
T1.DT_HDG_EFF, 
T1.ID_DERIV,     
T1.CUSIP           

FROM    
(SELECT 
he.ID_EXECN,     
he.DT_HDG_EFF, 
d.ID_DERIV,       
d.ID_CUSIP AS CUSIP      
FROM    
(hdvsudbr.deriv_popltn d  
INNER JOIN hdvsudbr.hdg_execn_job_deriv_popltn jdp          
ON jdp.ID_DERIV = d.ID_DERIV    
INNER JOIN hdvsudbr.hdg_execn_job hej    
ON hej.ID_JOB = jdp.ID_JOB        
INNER JOIN hdvsudbr.hdg_execn he           
ON he.ID_EXECN = hej.ID_EXECN) 

WHERE hej.CD_JOB_TYPE = 9
AND he.DT_HDG_EFF >=LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-5))) T1
```

My current output looks like this:

Some days there are more than one ID_EXECN (two, three, or more) and some days there are just one ID_EXECN, so the max on days where there is one should just return the same one.

```
ID_EXECN     DT_HDG_EFF  ID_DERV  CUSIP
40           11/8/2016   1        Z800
40           11/8/2016   2        Z801
41           11/8/2016   1        Z800
41           11/8/2016   2        Z801
22           11/9/2016   1        Z800
22           11/9/2016   2        Z801
23           11/9/2016   1        Z800
23           11/9/2016   2        Z801
24           11/9/2016   1        Z800
24           11/9/2016   2        Z801
10           11/10/2016  1        Z800
10           11/10/2016  2        Z801
```

This is the output I am trying to obtain, just the records with the max ID_EXECN for the given day:

```
ID_EXECN     DT_HDG_EFF  ID_DERV  CUSIP
41           11/8/2016   1        Z800
41           11/8/2016   2        Z801
24           11/9/2016   1        Z800
24           11/9/2016   2        Z801
10           11/10/2016  1        Z800
10           11/10/2016  2        Z801
```

So far, I have just been able to retrieve the max ID_EXECN for all days in the query, which would be 41 in this case, but that is not what I want. I want the max for each day. Other cases my query runs, but just returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could you window function `RANK` for this:

```
select T1.ID_EXECN,
    T1.DT_HDG_EFF,
    T1.ID_DERIV,
    T1.CUSIP
from (
    select he.ID_EXECN,
        he.DT_HDG_EFF,
        d.ID_DERIV,
        d.ID_CUSIP as CUSIP rank() over (
            partition by he.DT_HDG_EFF order by he.ID_EXECN desc nulls last
            ) rnk
    from (
        hdvsudbr.deriv_popltn d inner join hdvsudbr.hdg_execn_job_deriv_popltn jdp on jdp.ID_DERIV = d.ID_DERIV
        inner join hdvsudbr.hdg_execn_job hej on hej.ID_JOB = jdp.ID_JOB
        inner join hdvsudbr.hdg_execn he on he.ID_EXECN = hej.ID_EXECN
        )
    where hej.CD_JOB_TYPE = 9
        and he.DT_HDG_EFF >= LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, - 5))
    ) T1
where rnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, just needs a , after the CUSIP